# How to alter style of another element on hover of an ::after element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have this pseudo element as below:

```
.itembox::before {
    border: 2px solid red;
    content: '';
    top:25px;
    left:5px;
    right:40px;
    bottom:45px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

 .itembox:hover::before .title  {
    background-color: red;
}
```

It is a simple "div" element named "itembox".
I am trying to change the "title" div when the pseudo element is hovered over.
Above code is not working. My HTML is as below:

```
<div class="itembox">
    <div class="title">Risk Management</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot do this, pseudo element cannot catch hover event on their own. Only the main element can. Hovering the pseudo element will trigger the event on the main element

Comment: There's no way to use a selector to draw a relationship from a pseudo-element to another element.

Comment: @Quentin I don't think we need the duplicate for a parent selector here. Probably a one dealing about the hovering on pseudo elements